# How to retrieve count objects faster on Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My goal is to optimize the retrieval of the count of objects I have in my Django model.

I have two models:

- Users
- Prospects

It's a one-to-many relationship. One User can create many Prospects. One Prospect can only be created by one User.

I'm trying to get the Prospects created by the user in the last 24 hours.

Prospects model has roughly 7 millions rows on my PostgreSQL database. Users only 2000.

My current code is taking to much time to get the desired results.

I tried to use `filter()` and `count()`:

```
import datetime

# get the date but 24 hours earlier
date_example = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

# Filter Prospects that are created by user_id_example
# and filter Prospects that got a date greater than date_example (so equal or sooner)
today_prospects = Prospect.objects.filter(user_id = 'user_id_example', create_date__gte = date_example)

# get the count of prospects that got created in the past 24 hours by user_id_example
# this is the problematic call that takes too long to process
count_total_today_prospects = today_prospects.count()
```

I works, but it takes too much time (5 minutes). Because it's checking the entire database instead of just checking, what I though it would: only the prospects that got created in the last 24 hours by the user.

I also tried using `annotate` but it's equally slow, because it's ultimately doing the same thing than the regular `.count()`:

`today_prospects.annotate(Count('id'))`

How can I get the count in a more optimized way?

Comment: What if you add a `db_index=True` for the `create_date` field? After adding this, you need to first migrate the database.

Comment: Currently my field is: `create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)`

I should change it to `create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, db_index = True)`

Then  what? The same `.count` method should work faster? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @RobZ no, you still need to update your database with a proper column index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have it already, I suggest adding an index that includes both user and date fields (make sure that they are in this order, first the user and then the date, because for the user you are looking for an exact match but for the date you only have a starting point). That should speed up the query.

For example:

```
class Prospect(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        ...
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['user', 'create_date']),
        ]
        ...
```

This should create a new migration file (run `makemigrations` and `migrate`) where it adds the index to the database.

After that, your same code should run a bit faster:

```
count_total_today_prospects = Prospect.objects\
    .filter(user_id='user_id_example', create_date__gte=date_example)\
    .count()
```

Comment: It there a difference between your indexing method and doing `create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, db_index = True)`?

Comment: @RobZ yes, there is a difference. My version creates a single index that holds both fields in the desired order, which makes the query faster. In your version (2 seperate indexes, one on the user field and one on the date field) the database can only use one of those indexes, not both at the same time.

Comment: @RobZ an index with only one of the fields is certainly better than no index at all, but an index with both fields (in the right order, like I said in the answer) will be even better

Answer (score -2):

Django's documentation:

> A count() call performs a SELECT COUNT(*) behind the scenes, so you should always use count() rather than loading all of the record into Python objects and calling len() on the result (unless you need to load the objects into memory anyway, in which case len() will be faster).
> Note that if you want the number of items in a QuerySet and are also retrieving model instances from it (for example, by iterating over it), it’s probably more efficient to use len(queryset) which won’t cause an extra database query like count() would.
> If the queryset has already been fully retrieved, count() will use that length rather than perform an extra database query.

Take a look at this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#count.

Try to use len().